# How to handle an If-else condition in an Effect to either throw an error or return a response from an API?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am trying to check for a condition based on which I will either throw an error or continue down to calling an API which shd return a response. I'm not sure how to approach this.

Not very good in rxjs. newbie learning the ropes. Would the following code achieve this? ie in case I dont have a pizza id I would like to fire another error effect else call an API to get the pizzas

````
getPizzas$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<GetAllPizzas>(PizzaTypes.GetPizzas,
  withLatestFrom(
    this.store$.pipe(select(fromRootStore.getPizzaId))
  ),
  take(1),
  exhaustMap(([customAction, pizzaId]): any => {  // << assuming this is correct
    if (!pizzaId) {                       
      map(() => new BigProductError({ .   /// <<< is this how we approach this? just map? or should we return something?
           appmessage : "Boom"
      }));
    } .      /// <<< will control go beyond this point or is this more of an if-else condition?
    return this.pizzaService.getPizzas(customAction.orderDetails, pizzaId)
      .pipe(
        map((pizzas) => new LoadPizzasSuccess(pizzas)),
        catchError(error => of(new LoadPizzasFailure(error)))
      );
  })
);```
````

Answer (score 1):

You should throw the `BigProductError` error so that subscribers can catch it using `catchError()`. Since it is thrown there is no *else* block required for the if statement.

```
getPizzas$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<GetAllPizzas>(PizzaTypes.GetPizzas),
  withLatestFrom(this.store$.pipe(select(fromRootStore.getPizzaId))),
  take(1),
  mergeMap(([customAction, pizzaId]) => {
    if (!pizzaId) {                       
      throw new BigProductError({appmessage : "Boom"}));
    }
    return this.pizzaService.getPizzas(customAction.orderDetails, pizzaId)
      .pipe(
        map((pizzas) => new LoadPizzasSuccess(pizzas)),
        catchError(error => of(new LoadPizzasFailure(error)))
      );
  })
);
```

I would also use `mergeMap()` after the `take(1)` because there will only be one value emitted.

Comment: shouldnt i be dispatching the `BigProductError`? ITs an effect that we're trying to send out - at least thats what I assumed we should do in effect error handing?

Comment: @LesterGray you can `return of(new BigProductError(...))` instead of throwing it, but consumers will not catch it via `catchError()`. Which is fine if that's how you want to handle it.

Comment: there is an option of `store.dispatch(BigProductError)` - would that be also a feasible approach ie using effect to dispatch it and let the appropriate action-reducer handler handle it? if yes - would the `if { dispatch }return this.pizzaService` become more of an `if {dispatch } else { pizzaService }`? construct?